# Jade запись объекта

Tags: gulp, jade

Мое знание Jade - базовое, поэтому поэтому вопрос от новичка )))

Как можно(если можно) создать объект (не получая его из JSON или других внешних файлов) в **самом jade файле**

Моя попытка - при которой получаю ошибку `unexpexted text {`

```
-var profiles = [
    {
        'name': 'anna',
        'age': 26
    }
]
```

Причину понимаю, это из-за перевода строки. Все работает если записать это в одну строку, но при большем объеме это не удобно.

```
-var profiles = [{'name':'anna','age': 26}]
```

Может кто сталкивался с подобным и знает методы, как правильно это записывается (если такое вообще возможно), если нет буду грузить из внешки.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так

```
-
    var profiles = {
        'name': 'anna',
        'age': 26
    };
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, вернул изначальный код автора ответа - изначально он был абсолютно корректен и самодостаточен. В Jade блоки отделяются друг от друга отступами. как в Python, поэтому переформатирование сделало код ошибочным.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Большое спасибо! Буду знать. Редактировал исходя из кода в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

В Jade [блоки небуфиризированного JavaScript-кода](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) обрамляются при помощи символа `-` и идущих за ним строк с отступом:

```
-
    var profiles = [
        {
            'name': 'anna',
            'age': 26
        }
    ]

    // код сверху и снизу от этой строки
    // принадлежит одному блоку

    var foo = 'bar';
    foo += ' of gold';


p А здесь уже идут 
  strong обычные
  |  конструкции Jade
```

Блок кода заканчивается последней строкой  c отступом.